# Show and hide table based on radio button

Tags: jquery, html-table, radio-button

I have two tables: the first is shown and the second is hidden.

I'm trying to get the second table to appear when either "Yes" radio button is chosen in rows 8 and 9 of the first table.

If both "No" radio buttons are chosen in rows 8 or 9 from the first table, the second table should be hidden.

Here's what I have so far.

You can see a demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mrfisherman2010/nfmQF/3/).

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("[name=texting_dur_school]").click(function() {
        $('#part2_question').show();
    });

});



<table width="100%" border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><strong>Where has this happened?</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Yes</strong></td>
    <td><strong>No</strong></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1. </td>
    <td>cafeteria</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="cafeteria" value="Yes" />
    </td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="cafeteria" value="No" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2. </td>
    <td bgcolor="#ddeeee">academic class</td>
    <td bgcolor="#ddeeee"><input type="radio" name="academic_class" value="Yes" />
    </td>
    <td bgcolor="#ddeeee"><input type="radio" name="academic_class" value="No" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3. </td>
    <td>before school</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="before_school" value="Yes" />
    </td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="before_school" value="No" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4. </td>
    <td bgcolor="#ddeeee">bus</td>
    <td bgcolor="#ddeeee"><input type="radio" name="bus" value="Yes" />
    </td>
    <td bgcolor="#ddeeee"><input type="radio" name="bus" value="No" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5. </td>
    <td>after school</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="after_school" value="Yes" />
    </td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="after_school" value="No" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6. </td>
    <td bgcolor="#ddeeee">hallway</td>
    <td bgcolor="#ddeeee"><input type="radio" name="hallway" value="Yes" />
    </td>
    <td bgcolor="#ddeeee"><input type="radio" name="hallway" value="No" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7. </td>
    <td>sporting events</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="sporting_events" value="Yes" />
    </td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="sporting_events" value="No" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>8. </td>
    <td bgcolor="red">online/texting during school</td>
    <td bgcolor="red"><input type="radio" name="texting_dur_school" value="Yes" />
    </td>
    <td bgcolor="red"><input type="radio" name="texting_dur_school" value="No" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>9. </td>
    <td bgcolor="orange">online/texting outside of school</td>
    <td bgcolor="orange"><input type="radio" name="texting_out_school" value="Yes" />
    </td>
    <td bgcolor="orange"><input type="radio" name="texting_out_school" value="No" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>



<br />
<br />


<div id="part2_question" class="current" style="display:none">

    <table width="100%" border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td><strong>Identify the online/texting programs.</strong></td>
            <td><strong>Yes</strong></td>
            <td><strong>No</strong></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#ddeeee">Facebook</td>
            <td bgcolor="#ddeeee"><input type="radio" name="Facebook" value="Yes" /></td>
            <td bgcolor="#ddeeee"><input type="radio" name="Facebook" value="No" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Twitter</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="Twitter" value="Yes" /></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="Twitter" value="No" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Email</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="Email" value="Yes" /></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="Email" value="No" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Texting</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="Texting" value="Yes" /></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="Texting" value="No" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#ddeeee">Online Gaming</td>
            <td bgcolor="#ddeeee"><input type="radio" name="Online_Gaming" value="Yes" /></td>
            <td bgcolor="#ddeeee"><input type="radio" name="Online_Gaming" value="No" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest putting a class on those texting radio button questions called something like `class="texting_question"` and then you could use something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".texting_question").click(function() {
        var hasYesAnswer = false;
        $(".texting_question:checked").each(function() {
            if ($(this).val() == "Yes") {
                hasYesAnswer = true;
            }
        });
        if (hasYesAnswer) {
            $('#part2_question').show();
        } else {
            $('#part2_question').hide();
        }
    });

});
```

It will bind an onclick function to all of the radio buttons. Every time one of them is clicked, it will lookup each of the radio buttons that are selected and check their values. If any of them are set to "Yes" then it will show the other table, else it will hide it.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/JAAulde/nfmQF/5/

^^ Grabs all radios and assigns a click which filters for those which are checked and have value of yes. If that filtering results in a collection with length, we know to show. Otherwise we hide.

Comment: Using a class, as suggested by Kenny Wyland, would shorten it to http://jsfiddle.net/JAAulde/nfmQF/6/

Comment: How would add validation to the radio buttons that are visible? I can't figure how to do it with items in the second table if it's hidden. If the second table is hidden, then I don't care about whether the radio buttons are selected or not. I've been messing around with the jQuery Validation Plugin at jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/milk , but I can't seem to get it to work. I tried to make it work in jsfiddle but I'm struggling. Here's my attempt: jsfiddle.net/mrfisherman2010/t5qTU/9

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure. I have never used the validation plugin. Perhaps a new question posting would get you a wider array of responses.

Comment: I tried a new question but no takers yet. I'm not committed to that plugin. I'm just trying to make sure questions that are visible get answered. If the table is hidden then an answer isn't required.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("[name=texting_dur_school]").click(function() {
    var texting_dur_school_val = $("input[name=texting_dur_school]:checked").val();
    var texting_out_school_val = $("input[name=texting_out_school]:checked").val();
    if(texting_dur_school_val == 'Yes' && texting_out_school_val == 'Yes'){
        $('#part2_question').show();
    } else if(texting_dur_school_val == 'No' && texting_out_school_val == 'No'){
        $('#part2_question').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: That's not taking into account the other set of radios. He has 4 radios, 2 w/ value Yes, 2 w/ value No. If any Yes is checked the other table should show. If no Yes values are checked, it should hide.

Comment: Thank you guys so much for your help. Both examples work perfectly. I'm really learning from your different approaches to the same problem.

Comment: How would you add validation to the radio buttons that are visible? If the second table is hidden, then I don't care about whether the radio buttons are selected or not. I've been messing around with the jQuery Validation Plugin at jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/milk , but I can't seem to get it to work. I tried to make it work in jsfiddle but I'm struggling. Here's my attempt: jsfiddle.net/mrfisherman2010/t5qTU/9

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("input[type='radio']:").click(function(){
       if($("table:eq(0) tr:gt(7) td:nth-child(3) input[type='radio']:checked").size() >= 1)
       {
           $("#part2_question").show();
       }
       if($("table:eq(0) tr:gt(7) td:nth-child(4) input[type='radio']:checked").size() == 2)
       {
           $("#part2_question").hide();
       }
 });
```

I didn't add any attribute on the html code because i didn't want to change your html code
http://jsfiddle.net/joseadrian/nfmQF/7/